# PHP ORM Solution for SqlServer

Tags: php, sql-server, orm, data-access-layer, qcodo

I am searching for DAL or ORM (Only ORM no MVC) Solution in PHP5 that can efficiently access SqlServer.
I am new to SqlServer. and I need to code a part of ASP.net website in PHP5.
I am currently Using QCodo However its codegenerator is making some problem with ASP's own tables (?? the ASP Guys told me that its for ASP's Membership Management. and these tables are handled internally).So I need some alternative solution that can work in this situation too !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options, from more to less complex:

1. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm)
2. [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org)
3. [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html)

The three of them support MSSQL through PDO's [MSSQL Server extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php).

Answer (score 2):

I've wrestled with this for quite a while and there are a few key points that you need to be aware of when it comes to SQL Server and PHP.

1. The driver of choice is currently the 2.0 release of the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server. You can find more information about that driver [here](http://blogs.iis.net/sqlphp/archive/2010/08/04/microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server-2-0-released.aspx). I installed it using the Microsoft Web PI application.
2. As of this post, I know of only 1 ORM that supports this driver and that is [Propel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldriverforphp/thread/8b54e0fd-33b3-499b-a77f-4ea31177e12e). That being said, Propel's generator has a dependancy upon Phing, which is best installed via PEAR. After wrestling with trying to get all of this working in Windows Server 2k8, I gave up and I'll just be writing my own wrapper or using the native PDO functions.